# Знак ! в арифметических выражениях, зачем он?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Смотрел я как то, не так давно, почти что только что, код своего преподавателя, набирался уму - разуму, да попивал чай зеленый с коньячком, и вдруг встречаю я странную штуку:

```
k=k+!(k%2);
```

Углубился я в раздумья - "встречал то раньше я знак восхищения только в логических выражениях, а тут вот на тебе"... И как бы я часто клавишу F10 не нажимал так понять и не смог, зачем оно и что делает. Помню, как то, человек хороший, сказал мне мудрость вот такую, что напиши ты `int a=0;` a следом сразу `a=~a;` то `а` в мгновенья станет -1, так вот, возможноль, что и этот случай, который был описан выше, причастен к фокусам из этих серий?

Comment: не вопрос, а литературное произведение какоето...

Comment: Настроение просто хорошее)))

Comment: +1 за неожиданную литературу в программировании

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Да, это из той же серии, что и `~a`.

На самом деле `!a` эквивалентно `(a == 0)` и имеет тип `bool`. Но когда вы интерпретируете это значение как `int` (а у вас так и происходит, из-за сложения с целым), `bool` превращается в 0 или 1. Таким образом, как целое число наше выражение эквивалентно `a == 0 ? 1 : 0`. В частности, если известно, что `a` -- 0 или 1, то это просто меняет значение на противоположное: если был ноль, станет 1, иначе станет 0.

Таким образом, выражение `k+!(k%2)` следует понимать так:

1. если `k` было чётным, `k%2 == 0`, `!` обращает значение в 1, и в результате получается `k+1`.
2. если `k` было нечётным, `k%2 != 0`, `!` обращает значение в 0, и в результате получается просто `k`.

То есть результат -- ближайшее (сверху) нечётное число. Makes sense?

---

Такая техника, как в вашем примере -- один из примеров кода, за который одни обожают, а другие ненавидят язык С++ (и С). Специалисты, тяготеющие к С, обычно больше любят такую лаконичную запись, а те, кто видит в языке скорее высокоуровневые конструкции, чем биты и байты, часто морщатся от такого кода. Я отношу себя к любителям высокоуровневых языков, но мне такие лаконичные конструкции нравятся.

---

Вот [тут](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) собрано много примеров подобного кода. Почитайте! Ещё несколько мозгоразрывающих примеров на SO: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375170/useful-bit-twiddling-hacks) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274937/c-c-bit-twiddling).

---

(Вынес из комментариев) Кстати, обратите внимание, что более коротким (и возможно более эффективным) кодом, выполняющим ту же задачу,  является

```
k |= 1;
```

Он, кстати, работает и для отрицательных значений `k` (это не вполне очевидно).

Comment: Благодарю, за содержательный ответ, пожалуй, на днях ознакомлюсь с примерами)

Comment: @Djonny: добавил ещё несколько :)

Comment: @VladD, там у меня комментарии закончились.

Вы пишете

    ...  смысл булевых операций типа ! не зависит от битового представления чисел

это абсолютно верно. Просто реально мы работаем с двоичными машинами и программисту было бы неплохо осознавать это.

И тогда (1)

    k=k+!(k%2); 

можно записать как (2)

    k += !(k&1); 

Правда не уверен, что это многим будет понятно, поэтому в большинстве случаев (1) видимо лучше.

Comment: @avp: а, теперь понял вашу мысль, всецело одобряю. Хороший программист не должен замыкаться в высших сферах абстракций; надо знать и железо, с которым работаешь, и адекватно применять эти знания там, где нужно.

Comment: @avp: кстати, с точки зрения двоичной машины адекватный код был бы просто `k |= 1;`. (По крайней мере для `unsigned int`.)

Comment: Абсолютно точно. Что-то сразу в голову не пришло.

Answer (score 3):

Вот [[[[[[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules), возможно, пытался сказать что-то более-менее правильное. Но до конца он так вам все и не объяснил.  Дело в том, что логический тип в С++ - это алиас целочисленного типа, но, в отличие от целых чисел типа `int`, например, `тип bool имеет целочисленные значения в диапазоне от [0;1]`. Короче говоря, логический тип может принимать только два значения - `0(false), 1(true)`.
Сказанное мною вы можете сами проверить, приведя "логику" к числам так, например:

```
  int a=(int)true;  // 1 
  int b=(int)false  // 0
```

И приводить, кстати говоря, явным образом не обязательно. Обратный пример:

```
 bool a=48555;  // 1 
 bool b=0;  // 0
 bool b=-948;  // 1( из этого следует, что false`ом может быть только нуль )
```

Из всего этого следует, что эта "конструкция":

```
 k=k+!(k%2);
```

будет либо инкрементировать K, либо оставлять неизменным. Если (k%2)>0, то прибавляется нуль ( т.к !(true) - это false ), иначе - единица( т.к !(false) - это true).

**И никаких величин более единицы, как это вам показал [[[[[[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules) !**

**P.S** И вам, и пользователю [[[[[[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules) было бы неплохо ознакомиться с булевой алгеброй.

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо!)

Answer (score 3):

Знак ! обозначает отрицание. !0 равен 1, !все_остальное равно 0.

Смысл k=k+!(k%2); Если k четное, оно увеличивается на единицу. Более короткая запись k|=1;

Если разложить по шагам:

```
X=k%2
if(X) X=0; else X=1;
k=k+X;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
k=k+!(k%2);
```

Значит: k равно k плюс не(остаток от деления k на 2);
не(1) = 0; не(0) = 1;
5%2 = остаток от деления 5 на 2 = 1 (т.е (4/2)+1);
23%7 = остаток от деления 23 на 7 = 2 (т.е (21/7)+2);
24%2 = остаток от деления 24 на 2 = 0 (т.е (24/2)+0);
итак: если  k = 4 то k = 4 + !0 => k = 4 + 1 => k = 5;
      если  k = 17 то k = 17 + !1 => k = 17 + 0 => k = 17

то есть k увеличивается на единицу если оно изначально делилось на 2
***PS:*** забыл упомянуть: `!(любое число кроме 0) = 0`

Comment: Не верно:
   
    Значит: k равно k плюс не(остаток от деления k на 2);

Comment: @Asen а что неверного? Если не верно напишите свой ответ (или хоть поправте меня поконкретнее..)

Comment: В переводе на русский выражение 

    k+!(k%2)

означает *ближайшее нечетное равное или большее `k`*.

Почему так?

В машинном представлении целых чисел младший бит у четных - 0, а у нечетных - 1.

Comment: @avp: имхо это не зависит от битового представления

Comment: Ну извините уж :) Я C++ то не как не доучу а вы <<младший бит...>> :)

Comment: И мне кажется

>то есть k увеличивается на единицу если оно изначально делилось на 2

как раз и выражает сказанное вами...

Comment: @VladD, отойдите Вы от теории (определение языка и т.п.). У всех этих *"штучек"*  "ноги растут" из практической реализации чисел в электронных схемах.

Вопрос понимания  - в глубине изучения "матчасти".

Comment: @Rules, мой ответ посмотри, что ли....
И, кстати, убила реплика:

     Ну извините уж :) Я C++ то не как не доучу а вы <<младший бит...>> :) 

Ты что, C++ с домашкой по истории ассоциируешь?

Comment: @Rules,

     то есть k увеличивается .... как раз и выражает сказанное вами

да, тоже выражает.

     Я C++ то не как не доучу а вы <<младший бит...>>

без понимания, "а как оно на самом деле" (и не только в аппаратуре (машинных командах), но и (главным образом) в ОС), сколько язык не учите, а *нормально* писать не будете.

Comment: @avp: а что тогда насчёт такого: `k += !!(k%3) + !((k+1)%3)`? :) Почти то же только по модулю 3. Это работает, несмотря на то, что наше железо не троичное.

Comment: @VladD, а причем тут троичность-то? 

Операция `!` из любого (количество бит) двоичного нуля делает 1, а из любого "не нуля" делает ноль.

И к величине делителя (в операции %) это никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @avp: это да. но то же было бы верно и для троичной машины, и для гипотетической аналоговой машины, которая вообще не работает с отдельными n-ичными разрядами: не-ноль превращается в 0, ноль -- в 1. Мне кажется, всё тут растёт из того, что булева логика двоична, а не из того, что числа в представлении процессора двоичны -- то есть смысл булевых операций типа `!` не зависит от битового представления чисел.